# The plot function in the 'gRc' library gives an error (also in the demo)

Tags: plot, graph-theory

In the 'gRc' demo it is stated that it's possible to use the 'rcox' function to create a variable that can then be plotted with 'plot'. However, this does not work as R thinks the created variable is a list and not a graph.

`\library(gRc)`

`gm  = \~al:an:st vcc = list(\~me+st, \~ve+an, \~al) ecc = list(\~me:ve+me:al, \~ve:al+al:st)`

`m1 \<- rcox(gm=gm, vcc=vcc, ecc=ecc, data=math, method='matching')`

`plot(m1)\`

This gives the error:

`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`